# Use pygount in bash script with variable number of files

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to count lines of code in a project using "pygount". Pygount takes in a list of files or dirs and then counts lines of code, and then writes a summary to the screen (by option). However, I want to use my bash script on other projects so I want the list of files to be variable, and input as a file that contains all of the paths (files and dirs).

The problem is that pygount doesn't see that my variable is a list of files, so I don't get the proper summary out. This may be a bash issue? I can get it to work using an array:

```
--($:~/repos)-- x=( *.v *.vh *.sv *.svh )
--($:~/repos)-- echo ${x[*]}
axis_data_fifo_v2_0_vl_rfs.v axis_infrastructure_v1_1_0.vh xadc_controller.sv xil_common_vip_macros.svh
--($:~/repos)-- pygount -v -f summary ${x[*]}
INFO:pygount:axis_data_fifo_v2_0_vl_rfs.v: analyze as verilog using encoding utf-8
INFO:pygount:axis_infrastructure_v1_1_0.vh: unknown language
INFO:pygount:xadc_controller.sv: analyze as systemverilog using encoding utf-8
INFO:pygount:xil_common_vip_macros.svh: analyze as systemverilog using encoding utf-8
  Language     Files    %     Code    %     Comment    %
-------------  -----  ------  ----  ------  -------  ------
verilog            1   25.00   243   57.86      382   82.68
systemverilog      2   50.00   177   42.14       80   17.32
__unknown__        1   25.00     0    0.00        0    0.00
-------------  -----  ------  ----  ------  -------  ------
Sum total          4           420              462
```

But this doesn't work, where I put the file names in a file called "w":

```
--($:~/repos)-- cat w
axis_data_fifo_v2_0_vl_rfs.v
axis_infrastructure_v1_1_0.vh
xadc_controller.sv xil_common_vip_macros.svh

--($:~/repos)-- cat w | pygount -v -f summary
INFO:pygount:/home/de770564/repos/sysver/system_sims/test/aioflex/lines_of_code/dut.loc: unknown language
INFO:pygount:/home/de770564/repos/sysver/system_sims/test/aioflex/lines_of_code/lines_of_code.out: unknown language
INFO:pygount:/home/de770564/repos/sysver/system_sims/test/aioflex/lines_of_code/loc_gen.sh: is generated code because line 4 matches re.compile('(?i).*automatically generated', re.IGNORECASE)
INFO:pygount:/home/de770564/repos/sysver/system_sims/test/aioflex/lines_of_code/w: unknown language
  Language     Files    %     Code    %     Comment    %
-------------  -----  ------  ----  ------  -------  ------
__unknown__        3   75.00     0    0.00        0    0.00
__generated__      1   25.00     0    0.00        0    0.00
-------------  -----  ------  ----  ------  -------  ------
Sum total          4             0                0
```

And I tried different variants of this:

```
--($:~/repos)-- pygount -v -f summary $( cat w )
Language   Files    %     Code    %     Comment    %
---------  -----  ------  ----  ------  -------  ------
---------  -----  ------  ----  ------  -------  ------
Sum total      0             0                0
```

I tried `cat w` at the end, but got the same results.

Note: The file doesn't contain globs, but it does contain environment variables that are not defined in my .bashrc. The env vars are defined in an environment shell script that I run for various project specific settings. I suppose this may be the problem then? How can I get the shell to expand the env vars that are part of variable values?

Comment: Does the file contain globs or a list of filenames? If it's globs, you need the shell to expand those before passing to pygount. This should work: `x=($(< myfile))` then use with `"${x[@]}"`.

Comment: Thanks jordanm, but that didn't work. The file doesn't contain globs, but it does contain environment variables that are not defined in my .bashrc. The env vars are defined in an environment shell script that I run for various project specific settings. I suppose this may be the problem then? How can I get the shell to expand the env vars that are part of variable values?

Comment: By sourcing the file using `.` or `source`. The entire file must be valid shell.

Comment: BTW, note that `${x[*]}` is almost always the wrong thing: it concatenates all the list's elements together into a single string, then (because it's unquoted) runs that string through word-splitting and glob expansion. If you want to expand the list exactly as it exists, use `"${x[@]}"`

Comment: @jordanm, `x=( $(anything) )` is generally considered an antipattern, as per [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29). Best not to recommend or teach it.

Comment: @wesley, do you need them to be _shell_ variables or _environment_ variables? If the latter, then you may want `set -a; . yourfile; set +a`, to have automatic export enabled. (Shell variables are good enough if only the shell needs to be aware of them; if they need to be accessible to subprocesses, you need them to be in the environment).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy At least I didn't go with my first thought of using eval :). In this case one of the big pitfalls mentioned is the fact that globbing happens, which I thought was actually desired in this case, but I was misunderstanding the question

Comment: @jordanm, thanks still. It gave me some ideas, one of which was "eval". Still no luck though :(. CharlesDuffy, I don't need them as environment variables. Shell variables are good for me. I'll try what you suggest.

Comment: Still no luck. I can't get the environment variables to expand.

Comment: @wesley, if you show me a _working_ command line, I can tell you how to make a script recreate it. But if you only show pygount's behavior -- well, that's not where my expertise is, and I don't have time to spend to develop it if it isn't actually attached to my day job or non-SO hobbies.

Comment: That said, if your question is "how do I transform lines in a file to arguments or a command line", there's an easy answer, and it's "use xargs". As in, `<w xargs -d $'\n' pygout -v -f summary`

Comment: Or if you want to load an array from a file, `readarray -t yourarray <w; pygount -v -f summary "${yourarray[@]}"`